# WPF Determine Current VisualState Defined in XAML From Code Behind

Tags: c#, xaml, view, viewmodel, adaptive-design

I'm currently working on a WPF application. I'm using the Visual State Manager with `AdaptiveTrigger`s based on the `MinWindowWidth` to create an adaptive layout, which is all defined and controlled by my `XAML` markup.  I do not create or change states at all from the ViewModel.

I have a number of states defined, and I'm wondering ***if there is a way to determine what state the user's window is currently in from the `C#` code behind***?

I've seen ways to *create* and *change* visual states from the code behind, but I can't seem to find any suitable methods (if they exist) to determine the *current* visual state, when the Visual State Manager is being controlled entirely by the View rather than the ViewModel.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**
You can name the concerned VisualStateGroup in XAML and access its CurrentState property from code behind. You can also subscribe to the `CurrentStateChanged` and `CurrentStateChanging` events of the VisualStateGroup.

**More info:**

VisualStates are defined under a VisualStateGroup. Each VisualStateGroup contains a collection of VisualStates, of which only one can be active at a time. Now your window can have multiple VisualStateGroups defined under `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups`. - so it's not like the Window has a VisualState.

Answer (score 0):

Reference the snippet below.
In this example, the grid contains visual state groups. 
As a result, we retrieve these visual state groups from the grid.

```
VisualStateGroup _visualStateGroup = null;
```

...

```
var grid = ResourceLocator.Instance[typeof(Grid)] as Grid;
_visualStateGroup = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(grid)[0];

_visualStateGroup.CurrentStateChanged += (se, ev) =>
    {
        var state = _visualStateGroup.CurrentState.Name;
    };
```